# isValid() function from moment.js library returns false for something that should be true

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

```
const moment = require('moment');

var format_1 = 'dddd, MMMM DD, yyyy';
var date_1 = 'Thursday, January 03, 2019';
console.log(moment(date_1, format_1).isValid());// This returns true 


var format_2 = 'dddd, MMMM DD, yyyy';
var date_2 = 'Friday, May 01, 2020';
console.log(moment(date_2, format_2).isValid());// And this returns false
```

The first console.log() returns like true, as expected. Proving any date in the year 2020 the result of the isValid() function is false for this specific time format. Thanks for any help :)

Comment: I ran your code on this moment.js playground and both returned true https://codepen.io/robbyc/pen/eZLZJb

Comment: @Anthony - That codepen URL is not the code in the above question.  Not sure what that is?

Comment: @jfriend00 it is just a codepen with moment.js loaded; I changed the code to be what is in the OP and ran it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Year is represented as `YYYY` as per moment.js [docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)

Modified your existing code to get the desirable output below :

```js
var format_1 = 'dddd, MMMM DD, YYYY';
var date_1 = 'Thursday, January 03, 2019';
console.log(moment(date_1, format_1).isValid());// This returns true 

var format_2 = 'dddd, MMMM DD, YYYY';
var date_2 = 'Friday, May 01, 2020';
console.log(moment(date_2, format_2).isValid());// And this returns true as well
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.js"></script>
```